# Is a command with an argument before and after the command possible?

Tags: latex3, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a `LaTeX3` command that works the same whether its argument comes before or after the command. For example, I'd like to define `\squared` to be used as either `\m\squared` or `\squared\m` where `\m` is defined as `\mathrm{m}`. Both should yield `$\mathrm{m}^2$`. Here's the markup I've been working with.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\unit}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\;#2}}
\newcommand*{\metre}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{m}}}
\newcommand*{\m}{\metre}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \square { m } {%

  \IfNoValueTF #1 {%
    $^2$
  }{%
    $#1^2$
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

The command used as a prefix gives \square\m.

The command used as a postfix gives \m\square\ .

\end{document}
```

The first example typesets correctly except for a line break that I can't explain, but the second example also has a line break between the `\m` and the exponent. I tried making the argument optional but that didn't work either.

It's okay if the construct I have in mind isn't possible since I can make slightly different commands for use before and after the argument.

Comment: The line break is caused by the empty line in the definition, which produces a `\par` at each call of `\square`. I don't think it's a good idea to have such a behavior of `\square`; surely the way you're trying will *not* work: a macro with an `m` argument will *always* find one and `\IfNoValueTF{#1}` will follow the true branch in all cases. Also I can't understand why trying to reinvent the wheel: `\si{m^2}` is available with `siunitx` and is definitely clearer.

Comment: I know it's weird, but I want to create a command that works the way one thinks when writing, which is not the way LaTeX is designed. For my purposes, `siunitx` isn't appropriate. Besides, reinventing the wheel can only lead to a better wheel. There are needs that haven't been considered anywhere else yet. If it's not possible then so be it.

Comment: I completely disagree.

Comment: You can use `g` instead of `m`, then you can use `\square{\m}` and `\m\square`. You will also need to add `%` after `$`.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but do note that I've written _three_ entirely independent unit processors for `siunitx` to get one that will cover all of the cases correctly! Also, using units at the document level leads to some issues with naming (for example `\square` is used for math symbols, as is `\bar`).

Comment: My target audience is introductory physics students and teachers who won't want to learn arcane commands to write up solutions. I want logically and lexically consistent commands. For example, I have commands like `\velocity{}` that automatically "know" the correct SI unit. All the user need type is `\velocity{3}` to get `$3\;\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, TeX does not allow use to 'look before' a command, only to 'look after' (exceptions are primitives such as `\over` and LuaTeX callbacks to alter the flow of processing). As such, the only way to deal with both cases is to make them 'aware' of what follows. Thus one could for example do

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\metre}{%
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{m}}%
}
\newcommand*{\m}{\metre}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\square}{%
  \@ifnextchar\metre
    {\square@aux}
    {%
      \@ifnextchar\m
        {\square@aux}
        {\ensuremath{^{2}}}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\square@aux}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{#1^{2}}%
}
\begin{document}
The command used as a prefix gives \square\m.

The command used as a postfix gives \m\square.
\end{document}
```

which looks ahead at the token following `\square` and makes a choice accordingly. You can see that this would get unwieldy for a long list of units: one possible way around that would be to use a 'marker token' at the start of each unit, do a partial expansion and then check for that token. That might look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\joeh@unit@marker\relax
\newcommand*{\metre}{%
  \joeh@unit@marker
  \@firstofone{\ensuremath{\mathrm{m}}}% \@firstofone needed to remove "{" and "}"
}
\newcommand*{\m}{\metre}
\newcommand*{\square}{%
  \expandafter\square@aux@i
  \romannumeral-`0%
}
\newcommand{\square@aux@i}{%
  \@ifnextchar\joeh@unit@marker % Tests by meaning
    {\square@aux@ii}
    {\ensuremath{^{2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\square@aux@ii}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{\joeh@unit@marker}}=\z@
    \expandafter\square@aux@iii
  \else
    \expandafter\square@aux@iv
  \fi
    {#1}%
}
\newcommand{\square@aux@iii}[3]{%
  % #1 = \joeh@unit@marker
  % #2 = \@firstofone
  % #3 = Unit code
  \ensuremath{#3^{2}}%
}
\newcommand{\square@aux@iv}[1]{%
  #1%
  \ensuremath{^{2}}%
}
\begin{document}
The command used as a prefix gives \square\m.

The command used as a postfix gives \m\square.
\end{document}
```

You'll see this gets a bit tricky, particularly to cover many cases.

The bigger problem comes when you get to more complex units. For example, what would

```
\m\square\kg
```

actually mean? Getting the spacing and meaning right in more complex cases is what `siunitx` aims to do, and one part of that is differentiating between 'power to add to the next unit' and 'power to add to the previous unit'.

Comment: Thanks for the meaningful answer. You're correct about the ambiguity of `\m\square\kg` and I had not considered that issue. Now, the package I've developed (which I hope to release onto CTAN later this weekend) was begun about three years ago, long before I knew of `siunitx`. I began with `SIunits` and its syntax is so natural and intuitive. I use it mainly for predefined unit names and the `\unit{}{}` command. It would be VERY difficult to migrate to `siunitx` at this point, so I'm considering writing my own unit name support.

Comment: @JoeH AS I say, one problem with what in `siunitx` I call 'free standing units' is the names. 'Short' names (`\m`, `\s`, _etc._) are very likely to clash with other possible 'shortcuts', while `\bar` and `\square` are definitely issues the moment there is any serious mathematics in a document.

Comment: @JoeH At something of a tangent, I'm slightly abotu the 'natural' nature of the `SIunits` syntax: one of the reasons I wrote `siunitx` was that the `\usk` business is a pain.